# Can't find suitable controller action to render view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I'm trying to do this:

List of Counties

County 1 (*links to list of locations within County 1*
County 2 (*links to list of locations within County 2*
etc

List of Locations within County 1

Location 1 (*links to location page*
Location 2 etc

My routes are as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


 resources :counties do
   resources :locations
 end


 root 'home#index'
 get "/:county_name_with_prefix" => "counties#show_by_name" 
 get "/:location_name_with_prefix" => "locations#show_by_name"


end
```

My CountiesController is this:

```
class CountiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :extract_county_name, :only => [:show_by_name]
  **before_filter :extract_location_name, :only => [:show_by_name]**

   def index
      @counties = County.all
      @locations = Location.all

   end

   def show
      @county = County.find(params[:id])
      @locations = Location.all

   end 

   def show_by_name
      @county = County.find_by_name(@county_name)
      @locations = Location.all
      render :show
   end

   private
   def extract_county_name
     @county_name = params[:county_name_with_prefix].gsub(County::ROUTE_PREFIX,"").gsub("-", " ").strip
   end 

   **private
   def extract_location_name
     @location_name = params[:location_name_with_prefix].gsub(Location::ROUTE_PREFIX,"").gsub("-", " ").strip
   end** 


end
```

Counties index view is this:

```
<p>List of all counties</p>

<ul>
  <% @counties.each do |county| %>
      <li><%= link_to "Locations in #{county.name}", generate_county_url_with_prefix(county) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Counties Show view is this:

```
<h1>Domestic Cleaning Services in <%= @county.name %></h1>

<ul>
<% @locations.each do |location|%>
<li><%= link_to "#{location.name}"**,generate_location_url_with_prefix(location) %></li>**
<%end%>

</ul>
```

I can get this to work if I remove the code between the `**stars**`. However, what I can't figure out is how to get the list of locations to link to each individual location page - my attempts to do this are shown in the `**code marked like this**`. The database tables are definitely set up ok in terms of relationships/data. Any ideas massively welcomed...

LocationsController:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :extract_location_name, :only => [:show_by_name]

   def index
      @location = Location.all
   end


   def show
      @location = Location.find(params[:id])

   end 

   def show_by_name
      @location = Location.find_by_name(@location_name)
      render :show
   end

   private
   def extract_location_name
     @location_name = params[:location_name_with_prefix].gsub(Location::ROUTE_PREFIX,"").gsub("-", " ").strip
   end      
end

end
```

Comment: you are overwriting a route by sending both `/:county_name_with_prefix` and `/:location_name_with_prefix` this will not work as the second entry will override the first and since you have not shown the `LocationsController` which you are routing to it will be hard to help.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for that I have added the location controller

Comment: That's great but did you pay attention to my other comment about overlapping routes? This is very important. Rails cannot tell the difference between the 2 routes specified. I would change them to `get "/counties/:county_name_with_prefix" => "counties#show_by_name"` and `get "/locations/:location_name_with_prefix" => "locations#show_by_name"` so that the are not overlapping and will work as expected.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes you were absolutely right. It also got me to understand a bit more about routing so thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have overlapping routes

```
get "/:county_name_with_prefix" => "counties#show_by_name" 
get "/:location_name_with_prefix" => "locations#show_by_name"
```

These are ambiguous and thus the second will overwrite the first causing all of them to route to `locations#show_by_name`.

This happens because there is no way for Rails to distinguish `/county_name_here` from `/location_name_here`. Does that make sense?

Also there is no need to create a method to generate the route when you can create a `named_route` using `as:` this will generate a method for routing using the as name plus _path. e.g. `as: :hello` will create a method for `hello_path`.

I would recommend something like

```
get "/counties/:county_name_with_prefix", to: "counties#show_by_name", as: :county_by_name
get "/locations/:location_name_with_prefix", to: "locations#show_by_name", as: :location_by_name
```

Then in your view you can use

```
<ul>
    <% @locations.each do |location|%>
        <li><%= link_to location.name,location_by_name_path(location_name_with_prefix: location.name) %></li>
    <%end%>
</ul>
```

This will generate routes like `/locations/location_name_here` in the links so that they work appropriately.

You could however also scope these inside your resources like so:

```
resources :counties do
  get '/:county_name_with_prefix, to: 'counties#show_by_name', as: :by_name
  resources :locations do
    get '/:location_name_by_prefix', to: 'locations#show_by_name', as: :by_name
  end
end
```

This will generate routes like

```
county_by_name          GET /counties/:county_name_with_prefix                 counties#show_by_name
county_location_by_name GET /counties/:id/locations/:location_name_with_prefix locations#show_by_name
```

Although all of this seems unnecessary when you could just generate links like this using default routing for nested resources. e.g.

```
<li><%= link_to location.name,county_location_path(location) %></li>
```

This is because your nested resources have already created this route looking like

```
county_location  GET  /counties/:county_id/locations/:id locations#show
```

Which will call `:county_id` and `:id` on `location` and route to something like

```
/counties/1/locations/12
```

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried something like this?

```
<%= link_to location.name, county_location_path(@county, location) %>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. I'm using @location in the index as I want a list of locations under the county which they belong_to. The only thing I can't do is successfully link from the list of locations to the location page. So County_1 > List_locations_in_county_1 is fine. Its just getting from List_locations_in_county_1 > Individual_location_page I'm struggling with. Know I must be missing something obvious but it seems so difficult!

Comment: yes for the first you can try to separate your routes... dont nest them... write in your counties model has_many locations and write in your location model belongs to county ... then try to call in your county view instead of your first line @county.locations.each do ...

Comment: Thanks yes my models already were set up like that - haven't been trying to call @county.locations.each do it was a suggestion from someone else. It all works fine apart from this last link_to from the nested location results to the location page.